# How to make ellipse curve graph from $x^2+xy+y^2=1$?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, conic-sections, curves, differential

So I will write what did I get and what is my question.

**Question:**

The height of the island in meters above sea level is:

$h(x,y)$ = $\frac{1000}{x^2+y^2+xy+1}-500$

Calculate the equation for the shoreline. What kind of curve is this?

**Answer:**

So lets suppose the water level is at $h(x,y)=0$ , whereby the equation of the shoreline is given by:

$h(x,y)=0$

$\frac{1000}{x^2+y^2+xy+1}-500=0$

$\frac{1000}{x^2+y^2+xy+1}=500$

$500\cdot(x^2+y^2+xy+1)=1000$

$x^2+y^2+xy+1=2$

$x^2+y^2+xy=1$

$x^2+xy+y^2=1\qquad$*(*equation 1)*

So it is implicit ellipse curve.

**My question is:**

How do I make the ellipse curve graph from *(*equation 1)*?

I know I need to use partial derivative to get the graph, but I don't know how from *(*equation 1)*?

What I need is get *(*question 1)* into this shape in the below:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to put the equation into the standard form $X^2/a^2+Y^2/b^2=1$ by rotating the axes? Do you simply want to sketch it?

Comment: So are you asking how to **draw the graph** of this ellipse? That would depend on what you intend to do that with. For example, Desmos graphing calculator will accept the equation as-is and draw it correctly: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rfnmnsap62

Comment: Your equation $x^2+ xy + y^2 =1$ is quadratic in $y$ so you can solve for $y$ without any derivatives... This gives the description of your ellipse as the graphs of two functions.

Comment: @almagest look at the photo which I added to my question.

Comment: Make this coordinate transform $x = \frac {x'+y'}{\sqrt 2}, y = \frac {x'-y'}{\sqrt  2}$ and you will see your ellipse.  This transform rotates the coordinate axis 45 degrees.

Comment: @MattiP. thanks for the site, it will be helpful to check my homework but what I need is the step-by-step way to understand how to get that graph manually without any sites.

Comment: Following the indication of @frog, if you solve for y the quadratic equation $y^2+xy+x^2-1=0$, you get the solutions $y=(-x-\sqrt{4-3x^2})/2$ and $y=(-x+\sqrt{4-3x^2})/2$. It remains to draw the two curves.

Comment: @RedRose The image you added to your question does not help. That is only relevant for ellipses with axes parallel to the coordinate axes. You have an ellipse which has been rotated through $45^\circ$. So either (1) you need to know something about rotating the axes ($X=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta$ etc) or (2) you could follow frog's suggestion in the comments above.